# Understanding Python decorators - is this a variable in example?

Tags: python, decorator

I am reading the following tutorial about Python decorators [tutorial](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_decorators.php). Everything is more or less clear except the following code:

```
def call_counter(func):
    def helper(x):
        helper.calls += 1
        return func(x)
    helper.calls = 0

    return helper

@call_counter
def succ(x):
    return x + 1


print(succ.calls)
for i in range(10):
    succ(i)

print(succ.calls)
```

I cannot fully understand `helper.calls` notation. Is is just variable with no relations to `helper` function? Also how does `succ` function gets access to `calls`?

Comment: `helper.calls` is accessing the `calls` attribute of whatever `helper` is. Same as doing `my_list.append`, accesses the `.append` method. Here, you are simply adding a `.calls` attribute to the `helper` function, and using that to keep track of how many times it is called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python functions are objects, that means you can set variables too.

```
def func():
    pass

func.count = 0
print(func.count) # 0
func.count += 1
print(func.count) # 1
```

Answer (score 2):

We can rewrite the decoration to this:

```
def succ(x):
    return x + 1

succ = call_counter(succ)
```

So now you have a decorated `succ`. As you can see in `call_counter`, it actually returns a function called `helper`. And this `helper` function has one attribute named `calls` which is used to count calls. So now when you call `succ(i)`, you are actually calling that `helper` function.

And yes that `calls` is just a normal variable.